# Why do we have [:word:] but not [:symbol:]?

Tags: regular-expressions, syntax-table

I'd like to use `[[:symbol:]]+` in a regular expression but this does not exist in Emacs, see ad-hoc section in [`the manual`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Char-Classes.html).

**Q1:** what is the rationale behind this? I'm always happy to understand the design decisions that gave us the beautiful beast that is emacs.

**Q2:** is there something that works like `[:symbol:]` would? At the moment I use ugly handmade regexes like `[[:word:]_+=]`, listing just a few specific symbols that I know will occur in my application.

Answer (score 4):

> **Q2:** is there something that works like `[:symbol:]` would? At the moment I use ugly handmade regexes like `[[:word:]_+=]`, listing just a few specific symbols that I know will occur in my application.

You could use the special `\s` syntax which references characters with a specific [syntax class](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Class-Table.html#Syntax-Class-Table) in a regular expression.

In your case, `w` is the syntax class of word constituents, and `_` is the syntax class of additional symbol constituents. Which means that

```
\\(\\sw\\|\\s_\\)
```

matches any symbol constituent.

Comment: Great!!! I did not know about `\s` :-( That is very helpful.I'll accept your answer in a few days if no one addresses the 1st question.

Answer (score 2):

I can't enlighten you on Q1 either. You could always propose it as an addition.

Another approach to Q2 is to match the *entire* symbol by obtaining the text between a pair of symbol-beginning and symbol-end assertions:

```
"\\_<\\(.+?\\)\\_>"
```

Comment: Couldn't that match greedily several symbols on a same line?

Comment: No. `+?` is non-greedy.